# set global row definitionin wpf grid

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, grid, rowdefinition

I have a grid with two labels.

```
<Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Hello" Height="20"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="World" Height="20"></Label>
</Grid>
```

I know that I can add  for each row, but if I have 100 rows I need to add 100 rows definitions.
Is there a way to globally set the row definitions so that all rows/columns will inherited their property?

Comment: `but if I have 100 rows I need to add 100 rows definitions` - You don't put 100 rows in a `Grid`. There's no need for that, and you will need a screen resolution of `1209381203120398 by 12938042309842304` to show that. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can use a StackPanel instead, with a ScrollViewer around...

Comment: Ok even if I have 4-5 rows, is there a way to just globally set the rows height?

Comment: But is StackPanel will fill the entire width in the grid? Or maybe WrapPanel will work...

Answer (score 0):

You could always subclass `Grid`.  Set each child's `Grid.Row` property, and add the row definitions, manually when the control loads.  You could add a property to the control to specify a uniform height for each row.  For example:

```
public class UniformGrid : Grid
{
    public double? UniformHeight { get; set; }

    public UniformGrid()
    {
        Loaded += UniformGrid_Loaded;
    }

    void UniformGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
        {
            var rowHeight = UniformHeight.HasValue ? new GridLength(UniformHeight.Value) : GridLength.Auto;
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = rowHeight });
            Grid.SetRow(child, i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<my:UniformGrid UniformHeight="20">
    <Label Content="Hello" />
    <Label Content="World" />
</my:UniformGrid>
```

(Although, as some comments pointed out, the above is basically just a StackPanel only slower.)